# Global version of Cauchy-Kowalevskaya theorem

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, analyticity

Does there exist a global version of the Cauchy-Kowalevskaya theorem for linear PDEs ? Global in the sense that the solution exist and is analytic on $\mathbb{R}$ if so are the coefficients of the PDE. For reminder, the Cauchy-Kowalevskaya theorem only gives the local existence (under some conditions).

Example: $\partial_x u (x,y) +\partial_y u (x,y)=0$ and $u(0,y)=f(y)$, where $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$.
Clearly, if $f$ is real analytic on $\mathbb{R}$ then $u$ is real analytic on $\mathbb{R}^2$.
How to apply the Cauchy-Kowalevskaya theorem to recover this result ?

Comment: @Thomas, can you justify why you changed Kowalevski into Kowalevskaya ? In her papers she signs Sophie Kowalevski.

Comment: My bad - I only learned today that Kowalevski is also valid here. I got to know the theorem und the name Cauchy-Kowalevskaya (which is also used in the German version of the Wikipedia entry). The English one uses Kowalevski in the title, but Kowalevskaja in the body. If you don't like it go ahead and undo it.

Comment: It's just a question of different conventions in different languages and countries.  She was the wife of Vladimir Kovalevsky, so in Russian she would be called Kovalevskaya. But her papers were written in French and German.